# Efficient sql inner join query

Tags: mysql, optimization, inner-join

I have 6 tables, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` and `F`. It is a star schema where `F` table is the fact table while `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` are the dimension tables.

My query now:

```
SELECT * FROM F INNER JOIN A ON A.id = F.id
                INNER JOIN B ON B.id = F.id
                INNER JOIN C ON C.id = F.id
                INNER JOIN D ON D.id = F.id
                INNER JOIN E ON E.id = F.id
WHERE C.cellName = 'XOR' AND A.lib = 'd04'
```

I already index the `cellName` but this type of query is very slow because it looks on all the line in the `F` table and didn't use the index when I use `EXPLAIN`.

Is there a better way to let the the query to get the `C.id` and `A.id` by filtering the `C.cellName` and `A.lib` before searching in the `F` table?

```
  CELLPROPERTYFACT | CREATE TABLE `CELLPROPERTYFACT` (
  `libraryID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cellID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pinID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `toP` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `whend` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cellRiseID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cellFallID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `risePowerID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fallPowerID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `libraryID` (`libraryID`),
  KEY `cellID` (`cellID`),
  KEY `pinID` (`pinID`),
  KEY `cellRiseID` (`cellRiseID`),
  KEY `cellFallID` (`cellFallID`),
  KEY `risePowerID` (`risePowerID`),
  KEY `fallPowerID` (`fallPowerID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |


  CELL  | CREATE TABLE `CELL` (
  `cellID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cellName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `leakage` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `frequency` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descp` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `libID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cellID`),
  KEY `A` (`cellName`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=150366 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |


LIBRARY | CREATE TABLE `LIBRARY` (
  `libraryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `opcond` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workWeek` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`libraryID`)

) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=382 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |


DIM_CELLRISE | CREATE TABLE `DIM_CELLRISE` (
  `cellRiseID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `whend` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `begin_template_ptr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_template_ptr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `begin_template_line` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_template_line` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cellRiseID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1073635 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |


DIM_CELLFALL | CREATE TABLE `DIM_CELLFALL` (
  `cellFallID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `whend` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `begin_template_ptr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_template_ptr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `begin_template_line` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_template_line` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cellFallID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1162150 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: Have you added indexes for the joining keys  i.e. `F.id, A.id,B.id....` ?

Comment: that is primary key so i think no need to index?

Comment: A PRIMARY KEY is a UNIQUE key is an INDEX.  So, do _not_ add INDEX(id).

Answer (score 0):

Either A.lib needs an index, or C.cellName.  (Having both won't help, and won't hurt.

That is not a "star schema"; that is 6 vertical partitions.  I suspect you simplified the SELECT too much.

Please show us SHOW CREATE TABLE for all 6 tables.

Comment: i have add the table..why it is not a star schema? it basically look like this [link] http://www.diffen.com/difference/Snowflake_Schema_vs_Star_Schema

Comment: OK, it could be -- just that `id` is usually the PRIMARY KEY of the table it is in.

Comment: If i follow the sql in the above link, when i filter my cellName on where clause, it will look though all the row in fact table which is about ~2m row and this make slow, y it is not only look on row with cellName = xxx

Comment: After you add the two indexes I suggested, please show us `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that scanning the F table is actually the most efficient access path for this query. If you are going to use more than 25% of the rows in the table than a scan is faster than index access.

Answer (score 0):

Try using join conditions

```
SELECT * FROM F INNER JOIN A ON F.id = A.id AND A.lib = 'd04'
                INNER JOIN B ON F.id = B.id
                INNER JOIN C ON F.id = C.id AND C.cellName = 'XOR'
                INNER JOIN D ON F.id = D.id
                INNER JOIN E ON F.id = E.id
```